# MongoDB Replication in another GKE cluster

Tags: mongodb, google-kubernetes-engine, replication, bitnami, mongodb-replica-set

I'm using Bitbani MongoDB helm charts, and I deployed Mongodb as a replicaset architecture.

I wanted to use one mongodb as a primary and mongo as secondary. replication should happen on secondary mongo, which is deployed in another GKE cluster.

Can anyone help me on this configuration.

I have deployed 2 mongodb is two clusters as replicset architecture. and try to executed below steps.

I saw some blogs they are saying run rs.initiate() command in primary cluster. But when I try to run it, its say already initiated.

and they said after initiation command run rs.slaveok() and rs.initiate({_id: "my-replicaset", members: [{_id: 0, host: "primary-mongodb:27017"}, {_id: 1, host: "secondary-mongodb:27017"}]})

Comment: Does the [tutorial from the vendor on this topic](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/expand-replica-set/) answer your question?